# SQLite: Alternative Query for Nested SELECT Statements

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, date, subquery

Here are the relevant columns for two tables:

```
DataSources
-----------
Column: DataSourceID --> Primary Key

TimeSteps
-----------
Column: TimeStepID   --> PrimaryKey
Column: Date         --> (of the form YYYY-MM-DD)
Column: DataSourceID --> Foreign Key
```

I could have the same `Date` for multiple datasources, but with a different `TimeStepID`.  **I would like to find which datasources share a date given only a single TimeStepID.**

The query I came up with that works is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ds.DataSourceID FROM DataSources ds
JOIN TimeSteps AS ts USING(DataSourceID)
WHERE ts.TimeStepID IN
   (SELECT TimeStepID FROM TimeSteps WHERE Date IN
      (SELECT Date FROM TimeSteps WHERE TimeStepID = ?))
```

Is there a way to simplify this query without the nested SELECT statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want in the results is the `DataSourceID`s then there is no need for a join to `DataSources`.
Also, the query:

```
SELECT Date FROM TimeSteps WHERE TimeStepID = ?
```

returns only 1 row with 1 column, so there is no need for the operator `IN`.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DataSourceID 
FROM TimeSteps
WHERE Date = (SELECT Date FROM TimeSteps WHERE TimeStepID = ?);
```

If the combination of `DataSourceID` and `Date` is unique, then `DISTINCT` is not needed.